# Windows Universal Application Facebook login with error "not logged in you are not logged in please login and try again"

Tags: facebook, win-universal-app, uwp, facebook-login, windows-10-universal

When I try to login to my Windows universal app through facebook login, I get the following error.

"not logged in you are not logged in please login and try again."

I am using winsdkfb but understand that this issue is not reported only in Windows platform and do not think the problem is with wisdkfb library. I had gone through the same issue reported in Android and iOS but the solution did not helped me in windows platform.

This facebook login was working fine earlier and I have a platform configurations already available in "Facebook Login" tab of developer settings. I have configuration for windows Store and Windows Phone with corresponding SID. Login is working in Windows Phone but for desktop, it was giving the above error.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing the application, removed and added the Windows platform configuration in developer.facebook.com as per the suggestion from multiple forums but none of these testings solved this issues.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Below settings is required in the developer.facebook.com for this to work.

Under Products -> "Facebook Login" -> "Client OAuth Settings" -> "Valid OAuth redirect URIs", enter the below URL.
"https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"

This was not required earlier but when there were other configurations added, this redirect URL became mandatory and it started failing for the Login requests.

So please make sure to test all the facebook integration related features after doing any developer.facebook.com configuration changes.

Hope this helps others with similar issues.